# How to timeout function when a rest call fails in node js?

Tags: javascript

I have to timeout the function `uploadData` whenever the rest call fails due to some condition. I have tried with `setInterval` in a `catch` block but it didn't give me the required results. So how can I code to timeout my function in a failure condition within 5000ms? This is my code:

```
uploadData(filename,callback){
   formData={
    'filename'=fs.createReadStream(filename)
   }
 options{
    methiod:POST,
    url:url,
    auth:this.auth,
    headrers:this.headers,
    formData:formData
      }
 rp(options).then((repos)=>{
 var response={
   'file':filename,
   'status':'success',
   'message':repos,
    };
 return callback(response);

 }).catch(fn=setInterval((err)=>{
   var response={
   'file':filename,
   'status':'failes',
   'message':err.message,
  }
 return callback(response);
  },5000));
}
```

Comment: Your code contains syntax errors. Please fix it first so it will be easier to read it

Answer (score 2):

A good way to accomplish such a feature is to use [`Promise.race`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race) with two promises: first is the one which makes a request, and the second is a *timeout promise* which resolves after a fixed time. Example:

```
const timeout = new Promise((resolve) => {

    setTimeout(() => resolve({ timeout: true }), 5000);
});

const formData = {
    'filename'=fs.createReadStream(filename)
}
const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    url,
    auth: this.auth,
    headrers: this.headers,
    formData: formData
}
const request = rp(options);

// The first one to resolve will be passed to the `.then()` callback
Promise.race([request, timeout]).then((response) => {
    if (response.timeout === true) {
        return console.log('timeout');
    }

    console.log('api response', response);
});
```